# How to create schedule Power Automate getting data from Power BI report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector, power-automate-desktop

I have a PowerBI report and need to run a Flow that converts the data into a Sharepoint List.
I could create this flow, but the trigger is "When a PowerBI button is clicked".

I would like do this with recurrence with "Scheduled trigger", but I tried and can't. Does anyone knows what should I do? There is a way?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/execute-queries